# How do I interpret a stack trace of the form "at mynamespace.MyClass+B.A ()"

Tags: c#

I have a stacktrace in my program which contains

```
 at mynamespace.MyClass+B.A()
```

I want to understand what the `+` symbol after the class name means.

Below, the trace detail:

```
01-01 06:58:35.578  8189  8216 E mono    : Unhandled Exception

01-01 06:58:35.578  8189  8216 E mono    : System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

01-01 06:58:35.578  8189  8216 E mono    :   at FTA1769_Bootloader.Classes.FTAStartupStateMachine+B.A () [0x000de] in <32f83d28d4ae43cc80a2c093d1253500>:0 

01-01 06:58:35.578  8189  8216 E mono    : --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

01-01 06:58:35.578  8189  8216 E mono    :   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <a5d9585e686a4a1bbce8735d2cf30fa7>:0 

01-01 06:58:35.578  8189  8216 E mono    :   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_1 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in <a5d9585e686a4a1bbce8735d2cf30fa7>:0 

01-01 06:58:35.578  8189  8216 E mono    :   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context (System.Object state) [0x00007] in <a5d9585e686a4a1bbce8735d2cf30fa7>:0 
...
```

The thing is that my class does not have any declared inner classes. It does have an inner enum declared. Could that be it? (the code is obfuscated and it is hard for me to identify the elements)

Comment: can you show your exception please?

Comment: It means that `B` is an inner class of `MyClass`, i.e. `class MyClass { class B { public void A() { } } }`

Comment: Edited the question adding more details

Comment: Canton is correct, but keep in mind that this naming pattern is just a compiler *convention*.  It isn't "contractually" guaranteed by the language.

Comment: The trace details mention a "state machine".  Do you use `async` / `await`?  If so, the compiler is going to generate all kinds of support classes on your behalf from your original code. `async` functions in IL look *nothing* like you originally wrote them.

Comment: @BradleyUffner I cant seem to find this in the docs. but  [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.stacktrace?view=netframework-4.8) the general structure is documented.

Comment: Yes, I have async/awaits in my code. Ok thanks

Comment: @AlbertoAnguita can't you just debug? It should stop at the point where the exception was thown. Then you can navigate the stacktrace with visual studio

Comment: @AlbertoAnguita Here is a good write-up of how the compiler will create a state-machine from your original `async` code. https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/understanding-c-sharp-async-await-1-compilation